# How do I render User Control children at a specific location?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a very simplistic user control that looks like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="wfWindow.ascx.cs" Inherits="webfanatix.co.za.wfWindow" %>
<div>Just a test...[x]</div>
```

with this code behind:

```
[ParseChildren(false)]
[PersistChildren(true)]
public partial class wfWindow : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        RenderChildren(writer);
    }
}
```

And the usage thereof looks like this:

```
<wf:wfWindow runat="server">This content should go where [x] is.</wf:wfWindow>
```

I'm no ASP.NET pro, so how do I get the content to render exactly where the [x] appears in my user control?

RenderChildren is rendering my content, but it is only appended to the end of the UserControl output. I need it to go and sit right where [x] marks the spot.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's just so simple to implement this sort of behavior with PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the implementation to decide where to put the content, then look into [templated user controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36574bf6.aspx).

Otherwise, use a placeholder control and override the [AddParsedSubObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.addparsedsubobject.aspx) method

Answer (score 2):

Change [X] into a control of it's own that can hold other controls, such as a placeholder or a panel.

Then override [**AddParsedSubObject()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.addparsedsubobject.aspx).  The default implementation of this just adds the controls to the usercontrol's Controls collection - which means they get added to the end.  Override this to add them to your placeholder.

```
   protected override void AddParsedSubObject(Object obj) 
   {
         PanelWhereXIs.Add(obj);
   }
```